# adding alias to .zshrc "bad assignment"

Tags: 18.04, zsh

I am trying to create an alias for this docker command:

`docker ps -a --format="table {{ .Names }} \t {{ .Image }} \t {{ .Status }} \t {{ .Ports }}"`

I'm using zsh so I added this to my .zshrc file:

`alias dockerps = 'docker ps -a --format="table {{ .Names }} \\t {{ .Image }} \\t {{ .Status }} \\t {{ .Ports }}"'`

I' ve also tried escaping the double quotes `\"`, but every time I try to finish with the compile

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

it results in

```
/home/USER/.zshrc:129: bad assignment
```

EDIT: removing the spaces around alias : `alias dockerps = xx...` --> `alias dockerps=xx...` fixed it

Comment: Please use code formatting and show us **exactly** what you have put in your .zshrc. Is the space around `=` in the alias intentional?

Comment: ok, I used code formatting and copied exactly the line of code from the .zshrc file
the space is not intentional, I just removed it and will try

Comment: ok, removing the spaces solved it :D